# What is the purpose of baking a ultra high vacuum chamber?

Tags: experimental-physics

I don't understand the purpose for baking a UHV. I know it's to remove contaminants, but I don't know how baking would do that. Sure, heat may dislodge trapped dirt particles or may even break some down, but the particles would still be in a UHV. Therefore, I'm not sure how baking benefits a UHV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't just bake it, you bake it while pumping on it with a vacuum pump.

A solid contaminant such as a grain of sand may actually not be a problem at all. The reason a contaminant is a problem is if it contains substances that are at least somewhat volatile, and that will gradually evaporate when the system is in normal use. For example, suppose I leave a sweaty cotton sock in a beamline. The cotton fibers may have little or no effect on the vacuum, but my sweat will be gradually evaporating off -- this is why you can smell the sock normally. If I bake, the process of evaporation goes faster, and if I'm pumping while that evaporation occurs, the volatiles will gradually be removed from the system.